# Best way to restart a golang server on file saves

Tags: linux, go, vagrant

I have API code written that exists in my $GOPATH but the main file is elsewhere on the system. I'm trying to get my main file to exit and start and again whenever certain files are saved. The closest I've gotten is by using a combination of `find` and [`entr`](http://entrproject.org):

`find $GOPATH/github.com/example/example -path $GOPATH/example/example/vendor -prune -o -name '*.go' -print | entr -r go run /vagrant/script/api/main.go`

But for some reason `entr` fails to shut the service down before starting it again resulting in the error message:

`ListenAndServe: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:1456: bind: address already in use`

Open to any solution that allows live reloading of the go server, but the less configuration/setup required the better as I'd like to reuse the solution in multiple projects.

Not sure this is an issue, but I should also note that I'm using [vagrant-fsnotify](https://github.com/adrienkohlbecker/vagrant-fsnotify) to touch changed files in my Vagrant guest machine when saved on the host machine.

Comment: My first suspicion is that `entr` is killing only the `go run` process, leaving your Go program still running.  But the `entr` documentation says that as of 3.1, it "ensure[s] that all child processes receive a signal," and the current version is 3.6.  Your compiled Go program should be a child process of `go run`, so if you are using a recent version of `entr`, I guess that probably isn't it.  (Are you using an up-to-date `entr`?)

Comment: @DarshanRivkaWhittle I installed it with apt-get install today. I guess the program doesn't have a --version option so I can't tell which version I'm using.

Comment: Scratch that, it looks like for Ubuntu 14 (which I'm using) it's only on version 2.5. I'll try to manually install the newest version and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, you're using an old version of `entr` which is killing only the `go run` process, leaving your Go program still running.  Running version 3.1 or newer of `entr` will also send the termination signal to your Go executable, which should resolve the issue.

If at all possible, upgrade `entr` to the current version (3.6), or at least 3.1+.  If that's not possible, one solution would be to write a wrapper program that handles the termination signal for you.  That program would run `go run` and watch for the termination signal.  Upon receiving that signal, your wrapper would kill both `go run` and your Go program.

Comment: Yep the new version fixed the problem. Thanks